# Timeout issue with express middleware

Tags: node.js, express

I have a middleware which I using for token validation. Here is how it looks:

```
this.checkJwt =  jwt({
    secret: jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: process.env.AUTH0_JWKS,
    }),
    // Validate the audience and the issuer.
    audience: process.env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
    issuer: process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER,

    algorithms: ["RS256"],
});
```

Then I apply it to use with my route:

```
app.route(routes.getUserInfo)
     .get(checkJwt, this.userController.me);
```

Why when I rewriting my middleware with `return` statement it stops working? Like this:

```
this.checkJwt = (req, res, next) => {
    return jwt({
        secret: jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret({
            cache: true,
            rateLimit: true,
            jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
            jwksUri: process.env.AUTH0_JWKS,
        }),
        // Validate the audience and the issuer.
        audience: process.env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
        issuer: process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER,

        algorithms: ["RS256"],
    });
};
```

I got timeout exception with each request for this middleware. Seems like `next` function never touching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what `jwt` method is - custom middleware or just using `jwt` package?

Also I see that You're returning jwt call without passing `req, res, next`:

```
this.checkJwt = (req, res, next) => {
    return jwt({
        secret: jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret({
            cache: true,
            rateLimit: true,
            jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
            jwksUri: process.env.AUTH0_JWKS,
        }),
        // Validate the audience and the issuer.
        audience: process.env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
        issuer: process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER,

        algorithms: ["RS256"],
    });
};
```

result of execution during middleware call is `[Function](req, res, next)` which expected to be executed - not returned.

so if it's middleware try to use rewrite it like this:

```
const checkJwt = (req, res, next) => {
    jwt({
        secret: jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret({
            cache: true,
            rateLimit: true,
            jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
            jwksUri: process.env.AUTH0_JWKS,
        }),
        // Validate the audience and the issuer.
        audience: process.env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
        issuer: process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER,

        algorithms: ["RS256"],
    })(req, res, next);
};

app.get(routes.getUserInfo, checkJwt, this.userController.me)
```

But if `jwt` method is not middleware and it returns `true or false` as result:

```
const checkJwt = (req, res, next) => {
    const result = jwt({
        secret: jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret({
            cache: true,
            rateLimit: true,
            jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
            jwksUri: process.env.AUTH0_JWKS,
        }),
        // Validate the audience and the issuer.
        audience: process.env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
        issuer: process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER,

        algorithms: ["RS256"],
    });

    // if jwt returns something (:
    if (!result) {
      return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
    }
    next();
};

app.get(routes.getUserInfo, checkJwt, this.userController.me)
```

Comment: thanks! The first one is working for me. The second one completely skips middleware logic and just call next each time.

Comment: @neustart47 as I don't know what is `jwt` method I can only assume that it returns something that can be handled. But if first example works, so seems like jwt method is custom middleware.

Comment: one more question: what does this mean `jwt ({}) (req, res, next)`? What does this construction mean? This part `jwt ({}) ` is the method input parameters, so what does mean this part `(req, res, next)`? This is a question more about JS, seems like I missing something with it

Comment: @neustart47 `jwt({})` in Your case returns a function that takes same arguments when middleware called. But it's required to call that nested function too.

Comment: ah, I got it. Thanks a lot!